# DB2 row level access control: delete and pass userId

Tags: database, db2

Two questions :

1) I created permission (create permission...), how do I list or delete these created permissions?

2) A lot of examples using "session_user" or "user" as the user id in the permission definition, is there a way to pass a random id (instead of using session_id or user)?

Comment: And once done with this question, mark it answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can query the DB2 system catalog for which permissions have been created. The view is called [SYSCAT.CONTROLS](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0059052.html). Then you would perform a `DROP PERMISSION` on those you want to delete.

The `session_user` refers to the connected user and is used in the examples
 to check that the current user has the permission to perform that requested action. You could use any other userID, but of course it should follow the intended use. You would need to open another question and create an example to answer specific use cases.